# TOR questions and concerns

Tags: security

1) ISPs request bridges and blacklist them, that means obfs4 connections could be listed as Tor, does that mean the ISP is able to see  the obfs4 IP and connect your activities to Tor just like without obfs4?

2) If the ISP knows you use TOR, although you may not be doing anything illegal, could that make you a target and have you reported to an intelligence agency for investigation?

3) Is there any way to protect yourself from the above?

4) Is there any difference in what the ISP sees when using Tor Browser to when using Tails?

Thank you

Comment: short and easy: 1) yes **||** 2) yes **||** 3) [using bridges](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html#UsingBridges) **||** 4) no

Comment: perhaps useful for you to learn who sees what and when: https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https

Answer (score 1):

1. If the ISP can reveal that the IP address/port pair you're talking to is a Tor bridge, then yes, that means they can determine that when you send traffic to that IP address/port pair that you are using Tor.
2. Perhaps, if you are subject to a regime that considers private communication to be, *ipso facto*, evidence of something unsavoury, then yes, using Tor could make you a target.
3. Using a private bridge, which the surveilleur cannot discover by the usual means, is the best way I can think of for avoiding being identified by your communication with a known Tor entry point.
4. I don't know anything about Tails, so I can't speak to that specifically, however as long as they're both using Tor correctly (which I can't imagine they wouldn't be), the risk profile should be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

1) yes

2) Depends on your ISP and Country

3) You could route your traffic through an additional vpn which would make it impossible for your ISP to see that you are connecting to tor.

4) No